# The syntax of the command is incorrect in c

Tags: c

I'm using gcc compiler for c programming.I'm trying to run "for loop" but in command prompt when I execute the program it gives "The syntax of the command is incorrect".

The program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int x;
 for (x=1; x<=10; x++)
  {
   printf("%d\n",x);
  }
 return 0;
}
```

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Eq5U.png)

Comment: Look for `for.exe`, the executable that should have been created when you ran GCC

Comment: `for` is an [internal command for your shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd). Use a different name.

Comment: Hey Faisal, what happens if try build your binary with a different name like: `myprogram` maybe?
gcc for.c -o my_program

Comment: You can also try running your program by typing `for.exe`.

Comment: Use `gcc for.c -o for.exe` and execute `for.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Your computer does not understand that `for` is the name of your program because the shell has a builtin command named `for`. Give the executable another name, like `for1`, and it should work.

Comment: this is incorrect. the name for is not the problem. It is just that gcc produce for.exe and Faisal needs to call for.exe

Comment: @Tarick Welling , You're incorrect about being Dominique being incorrect. Both solutions (naming the executable differently, and using `for.exe` instead of `for` to execute it) are correct. (I personally prefer Dominique's solution; it's less error-prone.)